# CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to create a assets.ap_ package See the Console for details

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I wanted to build a new project for Android and output it, but I can not build it as an image like an error.

[image]

1

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to create a assets.ap_ package C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -Xmx4096M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" - stderr[ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:136) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.createSources(ZFile.java:1586) at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.makeStoredEntry(ZFile.java:1546) at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1625) at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.writeFile(ApkZFileCreator.java:158) at UnityPackageBuilder.addDir(UnityPackageBuilder.java:89) at UnityPackageBuilder.addDir(UnityPackageBuilder.java:83) at UnityPackageBuilder.addDir(UnityPackageBuilder.java:83) at UnityPackageBuilder.CreatePackage(UnityPackageBuilder.java:132) at UnityPackageBuilder.(UnityPackageBuilder.java:70) at UnityPackageBuilder.main(UnityPackageBuilder.java:27) ... 5 more ] stdout[ ] exit code: 1 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg, System.Int32 memoryMB) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunSDKToolWithReadLock (System.String[] command, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.AAPTPackage.CreatePackage (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, System.String package, System.String directory, System.Boolean compress) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.AAPTPackage.Pack (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, System.String package, System.String directory, System.Boolean compress, System.Boolean useAAPT) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.AAPTPackage.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32,

2

> Build completed with a result of 'Failed' UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

3

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

- Windows8.1
- Unity2018.3.0f2
- SDK installed

Answer (score 2):

In Build Settings, set Build System to "Internal(deprecated)", then click on Player Settings. In the Inspector go to the Publishing Settings section and check the "Use legacy SDK tools" checkbox.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you very much. But the "deprecated" and "legacy" words confused me. Maybe do you know another solution?

Comment: Google changed it's method of building android applications and enforced developers to use Gradle build tool, as a result, Unity implemented Gradle build option but it has few bugs so my answer is a workaround until they fix them in future versions.